# Laravel subdomain authentication - Wildcard DNS

Tags: laravel, wildcard-subdomain

I have a laravel app setup on a server accepting wildcard DNS calls. It is running fine, except that a user has to log in on every single subdomain.

So, something like....

**business.example.com**  , **news.example.com** , and **example.com** will require separate logins while I would like to use the  example.com cookies and propagate through the subdomains.

In other words, if a user access subdomain.example.com they should be logged in example.com so that it can be used for other subdomains.

So far, I haven't come across any going pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Tweak the `config('session.domain')` value to be `.myapp.com`.

Comment: In /config/session.php I changed  'domain' => '.myapp.com'  but that doesn't seem to work. Am i missing something? By the way I am on Laravel 5.4

Comment: You may want to clear out all your cookies after changing the domain value.

Comment: That worked. Thanks

Comment: OK, I've turned that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweak the `config('session.domain')` value to be `.example.com`.

Be sure to clear your cookies after doing so - it won't work if there are old per-subdomain session cookies still hanging around.